# Run .py file in current directory with -m gives errors

Tags: python, module

I have a simple script `a.py`:

```
# a.py
print(1)
```

I run it with `-m` option in the same diretory

```
$ python2 -m a.py
1
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: No module named a.py

$ python3 -m a.py
1
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: Error while finding spec for 'a.py' (<class 'AttributeError'>: module 'a' has no attribute '__path__')
```

While I know `-m` means [Executing modules as scripts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) and will change `__name__` from `__main__` to `a` in this case, I don't know why it caused error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

> Since the argument is a module name, you must not give a file extension (.py)

I.e. just run it as `python -m a`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want

```
python -m a
```